# Uniqueness Proof: Related to Division Algorithms

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Regarding the statement: Let $a\in \mathbb {Z}$, $b\in \mathbb {Z}$. Then there exists integers q and r such that $a = qb+r$ where $0\le r \le b$.

Let $S$ $=$ $\lbrace a-qb: q\in \mathbb {Z}, a-qb \ge 0 \rbrace$

Why does S have to be non-empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a>0$, let $q=0$: then $a-qb=a>0$, so $a\in S$. If $a<0$ and $b<0$, let $q$ be any integer greater than $\frac{a}b=\frac{|a|}{|b|}>0$; then $a-qb=q|b|-|a|>0$, and again we have a member of $S$. If $a<0$ and $b>0$, let $-q$ be any integer greater than $\frac{|a|}b=\frac{-a}b$; then $-qb>-a$, so $qb<a$, and $a-qb>0$, yet again giving us a member of $S$. The only remaining case is $a=0$; if $b>0$, let $q=-1$, and if $b<0$, let $q=1$. (The case $b=0$ should be excluded in the statement of the theorem.)

Comment: Why does |a|/b = -a/b in the third case?

Comment: @Jake: Because $|a|=-a$ when $a<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of modular arithmetic:

$$a \equiv r\ (\text{mod}\ b) \implies a = qb + r$$

In other words, $a\ (\text{mod}\ b)$ will always give a non-negative remainder $r$ such that $0 \leq r \lt b$, so there will always be at least one element in $S$.